# PHP gearman - calling a gearman worker within a gearman worker

Tags: php, gearman

I am very new to gearman. I am trying to write a PHP script to download scripts from a URL and upload it to user's google drive. sort of a backup script..

What I am trying to do is to call initiate a gearman worker process within the process to first download the image from source to a temp dir and then upload it to the google drive. here is the script:

```
    <?php
require_once "../classes/drive.class.php";
    $worker = new GearmanWorker();
    $worker-> addServer('localhost');
    $worker->addFunction('init', 'downloader');
    $worker->addFunction('upload', 'uploader');
    function downloader($job){
        // downloads the images from facebook
        $data = unserialize($job->workload()); // receives serialized data
        $url = $data->url;
        $file = rand().'.jpg';
        $saveto  = __DIR__.'/tmp/'.$file;
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $raw=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        if(file_exists($saveto)){
            unlink($saveto);
        }
        $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
        fwrite($fp, $raw);
        fclose($fp);
        // create a gearman client to upload image to google drive
        $client = new GearmanClient();
        $client->addServer();
        $data['file'] = $saveto;
        return $client->doNormal('upload', serialize($data)); // ensure synchronous dispatch
        // can implement a post request return call, to denote a loading point on a loading bar.
    }
    function uploader($job){
        $data = unserialize($job->workload());
        $file = $data->file;
        $google = $data->google; 
        $drive = new Drive($google);
        return $drive->init($file); // returns boolean
    }
?>
```

The problem is when I start the worker using `php worker.php &` The process starts but kills itself the moment I start doing something else in the console with message "DONE" printed on my console.

How do I carry my processes out? and keep this script running?

This is a vague explanation, but Please try to look into it and help. I am really new to gearman.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the work loop.

```
// Create the worker and configure it's capabilities
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer('localhost');
$worker->addFunction('init', 'downloader');
$worker->addFunction('upload', 'uploader');

// Start the worker
while($worker->work());

// Your function definition
function downloader($job) {
    // do stuff with $job
}

function uploader($job) {
    // do stuff with $job
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was completely silly of me! And in theory should an inside call work.. And can I just call the uploader method without creating a background process?

Comment: Yup, totally fine to have a worker that creates new jobs.